# How does libc provide functions with two names?

Tags: c, libc

> Before the advent of direct binding  (-B  direct)  libc   provided  many
>          functions  with    two  names.   For example, getpwent() and _getpwent().
>          These two names referred to exactly the    same  function  in  libc.

How does libc make two function names point to the same implementation?

I think it should not be as easy as writing the same code twice though.

Comment: Isn't it just a linker trick? I've foggy about the details but I think the linker uses a symbol-to-address map, and so can map multiple names to the same function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's done via *weak aliases* a "nonstandard" linker trick that's been around since early unices and that's supported by all unix compilers/linkers I know of. It's basically done as:

```
void __foo(void);
void foo(void) __attribute__((weak, alias("__foo")));
```

often with macros to abstract it a little bit. This makes it so the symbol `foo` will have the same address and type as the symbol `__foo` by default, but allows it to be overridden by a "strong" definition somewhere else.

Comment: How do I use the synonym form like `_getopt` and `_getpwent`? When I use them,getting error croaking about undefined symbols...

Comment: Use them? From where? They're not supposed to be used and hopefully they're hidden...

Comment: there must be some way to use both synonyms in user programe,otherwise there's no need to have the synonym.

Comment: No, the alias is needed for the sake of using **internally in libc**, not in user programs. Functions in libc cannot call `getpwent` because `getpwent` is not part of the C language, and the application could very well define a function called `getpwent` that does something completely different. Thus, if a function in libc needs to lookup a user for some internal purpose, it might call `__getpwent` instead. This name is reserved to the implementation, so it's illegal for a user program to (re)define it (invokes UB).

Comment: As for why you might be unable to use these internal functions, ELF shared libraries have "visibility" attributes for symbols, and a library can make some symbols "hidden" to prevent them from being accessed from outside. This is a decent way to prevent misguided folks like yourself from trying to access implementation-internal stuff and writing very broken, non-portable programs that break the next time libc is updated and the internals get changed...

Comment: the `hidden` attribute is on when function is declared as `static`,right? How does libc prevent those defined in ANSI C from overriden by outside?

Comment: No, `static` linkage means there's no external symbol at all; the symbolic name is gone by the time the `.o` file is generated. And libc does not "prevent" standard functions from being overridden. It doesn't even have to account for the possibility that they are, since a program which attempts to override them has undefined behavior and is an invalid program.

Comment: I don't think libc doesn't do anything to prevent overriding ,at least safari provides the so called **direct bind** mechanism to prevent this.

Comment: Any kind of early/direct binding (including simply using weak aliases) will not prevent the user application from defining a function with the same name as a standard function; it will rather result in inconsistency as to which is called, and different manifestation of UB. Such binding is almost surely either a *performance* consideration or a way to facilitate user redefinition of functions that *are legal* to redefine such as POSIX/Unix/OS-specific functions that are not part of the C language.

Comment: Is there a way to check whether a function name is taken by libc **programatically**?

Comment: Or more general, check whether a function name is already taken by a library it depends on?

Comment: A straight C program can use any name not explicitly reserved by the C standard for its own purposes, so you just have to read the C standard to determine what names you can use. For a program that depends on POSIX features, you also have to avoid using names reserved by POSIX. A correct libc cannot depend on functions from other libraries unless their names are entirely in the reserved namespace (beginning with `_`, etc.). There's no way to check any of this programmatically; it'd part of the contract between the implementation and the application programmer.

Answer (score 1):

getpwent() implementation just calls _getpwent() simple as that. The reason this is done is to hide some functionality from function calls and to avoid something called namespace pollution. This way you can create a sort of abstraction that allows you to hide things from the user. Also leading underscore and double underscore are system reserved and are backups to make sure that you don't override something such as in macro definitions.

Comment: you mentioned `leading underscore and double underscore are system reserved `,but we can declare functions with leading underscores,right?

Comment: you can but its not a good idea, the reason for the double underscore is just in case you redefine a previous definition the system has a fallback for the standard library, imagine if you overwrote a system define which caused odd behavior it could be bad

Comment: well names like _A are also reserved (that is underscore followed by a capital letter)

Comment: glibc is probably using a linker script or something to make the two symbols point to the same function though

Comment: That is another reason for doing this there are many different reasons for doing such definitions and you can check for yourself that we are both correct