# Where's glibc's socket implementation at?

Tags: c, sockets, posix, glibc

In glibc 2.22, in the `/socket` directory, the socket library implementation is located.
When opening any of these files, though, all I see is an error-setting function with some macros beneath it.
Here's an example file (`/socket/send.c`):

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

/* Send N bytes of BUF to socket FD.  Returns the number sent or -1.  */
ssize_t
__send (fd, buf, n, flags)
     int fd;
     const __ptr_t buf;
     size_t n;
     int flags;
{
  __set_errno (ENOSYS);
  return -1;
}
libc_hidden_def (__send)
weak_alias (__send, send)

stub_warning (send)
```

<sub>(Comment with license removed.)</sub>

Where is that `send` the `weak_alias` macro has as an argument? Where are these macros defined?
I think this is due to compatibility with some crappy old compiler but why do they still use K&R syntax?
And most important, **why is** `__send` **defined like that?**

Comment: Doesn't answer your question, but `send` is a system call, so you're not going to see much in glibc other than a thin wrapper around that call. The code that actually does stuff is going to be in the kernel. Also see the accepted answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672607/how-does-libc-provide-functions-with-two-names) for why the two names are used, and [this document](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Porting.html) for some explanation on stub functions.

Comment: https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/SyscallWrappers This is the first kind.  You need to look for the system-specific implementation that comes with the kernel.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a couple of things going on here.

First, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6673020/2399879), glibc itself cannot define random identifiers that standard C does not reserve, because standard C allows programs to define those identifiers itself. Names beginning with a double underscore are reserved for the implementation, so the implementation here defines the function `__send()`. The weak alias then allows the name `send()` to be used to refer to it, but also allows that reference to be overridden by a strong definition somewhere else.

Second, as explained [in the glibc documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Porting.html), for ease of porting glibc requires any machine-specific function to have a corresponding generic function. If a corresponding generic function can be written, then it should be, but if not, the generic one should be a "stub function", which essentially just sets `errno` to `ENOSYS` (not implemented) and returns an error. If there is a machine-specific function provided, that'll be used instead of the stub function. Since `send()` requires a system call, obviously it cannot be written in a machine-independent way, so there's a stub function for it here. So you should be able to locate a machine-specific implementation (or a variety of them) of `__send()`, for instance, at `/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c` in the glibc source tree.

Incidentally, since `send()` is indeed a system call, all you're typically going to see in glibc is a short assembly language routine that makes the system call. The code that actually does stuff will live in the kernel.

Comment: OK, I got it now I think, thank you. But `setsockopt` for example is just a stub too. Is it really machine-dependent? And do you by any chance know where to find those "stronger" implementations of the socket functions?

Comment: You can find the platform-specific stuff under sysdeps, but IIRC most syscalls are actually auto-generated. After all the user-mode stuff boils down to copying the parameters in a few registers, moving the syscall id to a register and trap in kernel (via `int 80h` on x86 and `sysenter` on x86_64). Again, the actual sockets implementation is in kernel, you won't find anything interesting in glibc.

Comment: @cad: See edit to answer for an example of where you can find the actual implementation for x86_64 Linux. And yes, it really is machine-dependent, because making a system call by definition is architecture-specific, you can't do it in pure standard C.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths Oops, didn't know `setsockopt`is a system call.

Comment: Alright, so glibc provides some stubs if the kernel does not implement some socket function, right? But that implies that the kernel and glibc are linked together at build time, doesn't it?

Comment: Actually they're system-dependent.  In other words it depends on what the actual code the OS exposes.  For Linux you can try digging into the source tree with the help of https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/

Comment: It's nothing to do with the kernel, here. glibc itself can be compiled on many different architectures. Many functions need to be written specifically for those architectures, because they can't be implemented in plain-vanilla C. The structure of glibc is such that a generic function must be provided for any function which has a machine-dependent implementation. If it is actually impossible to write such a generic function, one is still provided, but it will be stub function that just returns an error.

Answer (score 4):

Generally the socket functions like `send`, `bind`, and `socket` are system calls, which means they are provided by the operating system directly. Notice on a unix system you would type `man 2 socket` compared to `man 3 fopen`. The former is a system call and the latter is a library function. So glibc isn't providing any of the functionality here which is why you can't find the implementation in the glibc sources.

As to the `__send` and the `weak_alias`, what's going on there is that glibc is creating a **weak binding** from `send` to `__send` which basically means that if you call send and there is no other implementation available, you'll get glibc's `__send`. This just returns `ENOSYS` precisely because there is no implementation available. If there is a real implementation, it will override the weak binding.

The `sysdeps` directory is where all the dirty work is done to wrap systems calls. For example, look at `sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/syscalls.list` and you'll see the mapping from C function calls to the OS syscalls for that OS and architecture. Look at `syscall.S` in the same directory and you'll see how the syscalls are actually made. In short, there is no real user-level code implementing syscalls, the libc implementation puts the number associated with the syscall in a register and then executes the `syscall` instruction. All of the real implementation is in the kernel.

Comment: Alright, but these system calls have to be wrapped up to library functions **somewhere**. And what about `accept`, `accept4`, `setsockopt`, etc.? But I understand how that all is supposed to work now, thank you. My question is where to find the actual function implementations now.

Comment: @cad  I added some notes in my answer about how syscalls work. Does that answer your questions?

Comment: Yes, I think it does. Thanks. :-)